# Step by Step to get on to Telnet ? Management?

Tags: vlan, ssh

I need to combine 3 switches in to 1 terminal so i dont have to keep switching my console cable to each switch,

so its something called telnet., there is also something about making a "management vlan" so im supposed this is the vlan ip address i telnet onto.

Not sure how to do this, if someone can explain and show me step by step id extremely appreciate that, thanks.

Comment: Buddy, you seriously need to read some info first. If you need some help, you can begin providing some info about your equipment.

Comment: I tried and I am a little lost between management vlan and telnet and how they relate. I have 2 3560s and 1 2960 switch. And so I want 3 telnet sessions, il be connecting a firewall later

Comment: Do you have any kind of managment network??, cause you need 3 IPs, one for every switch

Comment: Orlando, you seriously need to read some info first.  He does not want to keep switching his Console cable.  Console access does not rely on IP addresses.  He does not need any IP addresses at all.  He needs a Terminal Server.

Comment: His question is vague enough that configuring the 3 switches with IP addresses and telnet access would basically satisfy his requirements.

Comment: "i dont have to keep switching my console cable to each switch"

Comment: And telnet would satisfy that. 3 switches with telnet means I don't have to keep switching a console cable to access each switch. I can open all 3 switches in separate telnet sessions. There isn't anything in his current question that requires the access method to be via console. "need to combine 3 switches in to 1 terminal" could suggest a terminal server. Reading the overall question I just came to the conclusion that he wanted simultaneous access to the switches. If its for a lab then a terminal server would be better but as its not a business network I think labs fall under off topic?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the steps described upside.
Only some explanation

```
router#configure terminal

router(config)#username user1 password pass1
router(config)#username user2 password pass2
router(config)#line vty 0 4
```

! Whe you put login local i to line vty 0 4
! You are refering to all the local users
! Those that you are declared like !username

```
router(config-line)#login local
```

Answer (score 1):

Console access into several networking devices is provided via a Terminal Server.

[Configure Terminal Server through Menu Options](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/dial-access/asynchronous-connections/200462-Terminal-server-configuration-using-Menu.html)

Cisco Router configured as Terminal Server with an Async module like HWIC-8A, called octopus cable.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
switch> en
switch# conf t
switch(config)# username cisco priv 15 password cisco
switch(config)# int vlan 1
switch(config-if)# ip addr 192.168.0.200 255.255.255.0
switch(config-if)# no shut
switch(config-if)# line vty 0 4
switch(config-line)# login local
switch(config-line)# end
switch()# wr mem
```

This configures a user to login with, creates a vlan interface to connect to, and then allows telnet to one of the virtual lines (vty). Ignore the management vlan for now, vlan 1 works fine. Plug your ethernet cable into the switch and telnet to 192.168.0.200.

If you have any questions, everyone here is happy to help, but you should be able to find this stuff in numerous docs online.

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ios-nx-os-software/ios-software-releases-110/45843-configpasswords.html
and
https://supportforums.cisco.com/document/19756/configuring-telnet-console-and-aux-port-passwords

Comment: i am doing that and trying to access vlan from another switch, but it says 
Switch#telnet 192.168.10.11
Trying 192.168.10.11 ... Open


Password required, but none set

[Connection to 192.168.10.11 closed by foreign host]  do i have to do those commands on the other switches for it to work

Comment: @Stan234 You can try going into line vty 0 4 and entering "login" and "password cisco". You shouldn't need to do this though if you correctly have "login local" on the lines and a user created.